# Clang Static Analyzer for Xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm, clang

Do we still need Clang Static Analyzer for XCode4? or the built in one is already good enough to use?

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

If not, anyone know how to integrate the above one with Xcode4?

Thanks

Comment: Note that it is possible to use versions of the static analyser that are more recent than the ones shipped with Xcode. In fact, a new version was released today with introductory support for Objective-C++: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/release_notes.html#checker_256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in static analyzer uses Clang to generate its results. You should see nearly identical (or better) output from the “Build” > “Build and Analyze...” command.

Comment: @Howard: The Clang Static Analyzer comes with Xcode 4.  Xcode 3 uses the GCC analyzer as far as I know.

Comment: @sudo Xcode 3 also used Clang. There has never been a "GCC analyzer." You're probably confusing the default compiler choice of GCC vs llvm-gcc vs Clang into this.

Comment: @ohmantics: Thanks for clearing that up.  I was confusing the two. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Noah's answer...  The Static Analyzer is great!

You can turn it on to run by default every-time you build.  This helps catch problems faster.

[image]

The only exception is if you have a very large project and static analysis takes a long time.  For most projects it should be a good idea.