# Add a UITableView as a subview crash only on simulator iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator

Is there a problem with adding a `UITableView` as a subview of a`UIView`? I had a line of code that was working for months, and recently broke after I updated `XCode` to 4.6.3. Long story short, I was returning TableViewTwo as a subview of a `UIView` as a footer of TableViewOne. Please don't ask me why this is necessary, it is just convenient for what I am doing. Well, the app would always crash on the simulator, but not on the device. It would give me a bizarre error and an opaque call stack. The error said unrecognized selector(numberOfSections)sent to instance. Yes, the selector was numberOfSections and not the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` in the `UITableViewDataSource`. Well, when I returned the UITableViewTwo as UITableViewOne's footer..everything started working. Does anyone know if there is a problem with adding a `UITableView` as a subview of a `UIView`? For more information - see this SO Post([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497590/numberofsections-being-called-ios%20%22link))

Comment: Sounds like you may be over-releasing. Try turning on Zombies and recreating the problem.

Comment: I am using ARC and Zombies are on. It crashes because of an unrecognized selector